# Android app not listing in playstore

Tags: android, google-play, publish

I published my android app in Google play store. Now this app not getting listed, when I search using the app name. But I can see the app if I search using my developer name. I published this app on yesterday. Any chance to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the app is published in `beta` or `alpha` version.

Comment: this was now showing in 126th place. how can i make this at topper? is this based on popularity?

Comment: Its based on varying factors, popularity is a big one but whether it follows the Android guidelines also has an affect, i.e. if it doesn't for whatever reason and if the app is not regularly updated could have an adverse affect on how high in the rankings it appears